# How to use an inline animation of a svg with a javascript on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I am currently working with svg on a web project. I am making buildings out of polygons (45 polygons to be exact) the idea is to change the points of the polygons when you click on a button. So that it will make an animation in between, thus making the building switch into a different building.

I managed to make the animation inline on the svg so that it will animate when you open the page (with a delay for now). But what i am now trying to do is that when you click a button the inline animation will fire.

this is one line of code from one polygon.

```
<polygon  class="b1" fill="#DCDDDB" points="555,114 552.5,416 568.5,413.004     ">
    <animate begin="8000ms" attributeName="points" dur="5000ms" to="473.999,335.287 470.845,482.398 461.808,325.766" fill="freeze"/>
</polygon>
```

I hope someone can help me.
I tried doing it with css3 -webkit-clip-path but this takes a long time to create the polygons. It's not entirely necessary to have the svg inline but it does need to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, get the animation element you want (easier if you've given it an id so you can use document.getElementById) and call `element.beginElement()`

Comment: thanks! this works pretty wel, only problem is i have 45 polygons with each seperate animations so it's gonna be a lot of work! but thanks for the code!